# php and django on the same lighttpd server

Tags: php, python, django, lighttpd

I have working lighttpd + django server but i wanna php too for example:
www.mydomian.com is django homepage and www.mydomian.com/owncloud is owncloud distribution. Is posible to do that? Really sorry for my terrible english ;) And here is my lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",

)
server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

$SERVER["socket"] == "localhost:443" {
    ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/server.pem"  
    }
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/owncloud/data/" {
        url.access-deny = ("")
}

#$SERVER["socket"] == "localhost:8000" {
#server.document-root = "/var/www/"   
# prawa dostępu dla "http"


fastcgi.server += (
    "/projekt.fcgi" => (
        "main" => (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 3033,
            #"socket" => "/var/www/projekt.sock",
            "check-local" => "disable",
        )
    )
)
fastcgi.server += (
    "/admin.fcgi" => (
        "admin" => (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 3033,
            #"socket" => "/var/www/projekt.sock",
            "check-local" => "disable",
        )
    )
)
alias.url = (
    "/static" => "/var/www/static",
    "/media" => "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/",
)
url.rewrite-once = (
"^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
"^(/Media.*)$" => "$1",
"^(/.*)$" => "/projekt.fcgi$1",
"^(/owncloud.*)$" => "index.php$1",
)
#}
```

And This:

```
# -*- depends: fastcgi -*-
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/fastcgi.txt.gz
# http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOptions#mod_fastcgi-fastcgi

## Start an FastCGI server for php (needs the php5-cgi package)
fastcgi.server += ( ".php" => 
    ((
        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
        "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket",
        "max-procs" => 1,
        "bin-environment" => ( 
            "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
            "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
        ),
        "bin-copy-environment" => (
            "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
        ),
        "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
    ))
)
```

Thank you for any help,
Sierran

## EDIT

Now work great. But SSL work only on server IP not in domian. Updated config file:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",

)
server.document-root        = "/var/www/"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

#$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
#   ssl.engine = "enable"
#        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/server.pem"  
#   server.name = "mydomian.eu"
#      
#}


$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/owncloud/data/" {
        url.access-deny = ("")
}


$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    ssl.engine = "enable"
    ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/server.pem"
    $HTTP["host"] == "mydomian.eu" {
            ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/mydomian.eu.pem" 
        }
    }

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(www\.)?mydomian\.eu" {
server.document-root = "/var/www/" 
fastcgi.server += (
    "/projekt.fcgi" => (
        "main" => (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 3033,
            #"socket" => "/var/www/projekt.sock",
            "check-local" => "disable",
        )
    )
)

url.rewrite-once = (
"^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
"^(/Media.*)$" => "$1",
"^(.*)$" => "/projekt.fcgi$1",
)
}

alias.url = (
    "/static" => "/var/www/static",
    "/media" => "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what type of server-rendering software you're running (eg. Apache, lighttpd, etc.) so long as you can install the necessary PHP and Python packages on the OS itself (with any *nix-server OS, like Ubuntu-server/CentOS, this is very easy to do).

Although I'm not familiar with lighttpd, what I would consider is to instead map the owncloud software to a subdomain:

owncloud.mydomain.com

Dealing with subdomains is much easier than /link URLs. Also, you will avoid conflicts with /link as you may want to create more links within django itself (for other pages).

What you will need to do is to create special use-cases for the different parts of your website using your lighttpd software. For example, you will make a provision for:

mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com
owncloud.mydomain.com

I hope my logic makes sense to you. If you need more info, comment on my post and we can edit it until the right answer is available.

Comment: Thank you for aneswer. I search and it's preety simple to do when I have domian but for now I only have ip addres on my server :< I will try more in home.

Comment: It's not very difficult to get your domain mapped to your ip address of the server. Just go into your domain company account and map the server ip address to the domain (unless you already know that). Goodluck.

Comment: Working django + php but now ssl not :< Any advice?

Comment: I've used SSL before and from what I can recall, it maps to a certain domain like: www.mydomain.com . It may only work for www and not for owncloud.mydomain.com (which may require it's own certificate). Try speaking to the domain company and see what they say.

Comment: But cert for mydomian.com doesen't work too. I rly don't know what to do.

Comment: Oh yes, you need to wait for a little while for SSL to take effect. You should see https after a while (not immediately).